# Lat/Long -> UK Easting/Northing?

Tags: javascript, c#, coordinate-system

I have a fairly accurate formula (implemented in C#), which allows me to convert UK Eastings/Northings to WGS84 Latitudes and Longitudes. Despite extensive Google searches, I could not find a formula to perform the reverse transformation. Could anyone point me in the right direction (a JavaScript/C# example would be ideal)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend using something like the proj4 library, which has wrappers in several languages, including JavaScript - [Proj4JS](http://proj4js.org/). For C#, there's [proj4net](https://proj4net.codeplex.com/)

It has the advantage you can translate between all sorts of projections, not just OSGB.

I'm not a great JS developer, but something like this should do the trick to convert OSGB back to WGS84

**EDIT**

oops.. you want the inverse transform.Just swap the two projections around in the proj4 call :)

```
var osgb = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs ';
var wgs84 = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ';
proj4(osgb,wgs84,[200000,500000]);
```

You can get proj4 strings for any projection using the [epsg.io](http://www.epsg.io) website

Comment: proj.net, also available as nuget package, seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

There is a JavaScript from [Convert between Latitude/Longitude & OS National Grid References](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html) which converts between easting/northings to lon/lat, which could be helpful.

It is also available in [GitHub](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy/blob/master/osgridref.js)

Comment: Great. Will check asap.